# Indirect pointers to mapped libraries functions assignment - C - OSX

Tags: c, macos, assembly, dynamic-library, mach-o

Given the following simple code snippet:

```
int main (void) {
    void* foo =  scanf;
    void* bar = sscanf;
}
```

Here's the disassembly (Taken from the mach-o executable):

[image]

Small part of the non-lazy symbol pointers:

[image]

Small part of the symbol table:

[image]

I don't seem to understand the 5th and the 6th lines in the executable file (The movq of scanf & sscanf into rax/rcx).
How do foo and bar (eventually) have the addresses of scanf & sscanf respectively.
I think that it has something to do with the dynamic libraries which are mapped to the process (And the non-lazy symbol pointers most likely point there or something) but I can't understand how.

thanks

Comment: note : Assignment of function pointer to `void *` is not allowed in C.

Answer (score 1):

[dyld](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dyld.1.html), the dynamic linker, is responsible for binding symbols. To see what happens, first compile your test project with the `-fno-pie` option in order to disable Position Independent Executable. This way the offset you see in MachOView will be the same at runtime. Then launch the executable with the `DYLD_PRINT_BINDINGS` environment variable set to `YES`. Here is the result:

```
$ DYLD_PRINT_BINDINGS=YES ./a.out 
dyld: bind: a.out:0x100001010 = libsystem_c.dylib:_scanf, *0x100001010 = 0x7FFF94578017
dyld: bind: a.out:0x100001018 = libsystem_c.dylib:_sscanf, *0x100001018 = 0x7FFF94578707
...
```

Answer (score 1):

The generated code loads the address of `scanf` from the non-lazy symbol pointer. There's nothing special there. As dyld loads an executable it "binds" each non-lazy symbol pointer, setting its value to the symbol's correct address.

Non-lazy symbol pointers are used for references that (1) point to something in a different library, and (2) are data references, not calls to a function. In your example, you're not calling `scanf` directly so it's a data reference, and `scanf` is not in your executable so it's a reference to a different library.

References within the same executable used a fixed PC-relative offset: the compiler and linker know that the code and the data will be loaded adjacent to each other so they can choose the offset at build time. References for function calls are lazy: at runtime the first call to the function is routed through dyld first, which looks up the symbol and binds the lazy symbol pointer for future calls.

As 0xced pointed out, you can set environment variable `DYLD_PRINT_BINDINGS` to watch dyld work. The dyld man page describes other variables you can set.